# Show $\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_{0}^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$ is Lebesgue Integrable over $(0, \infty)$ for $\alpha$ real and positive.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I want to show $\Gamma(\alpha) = \int ^{\infty} _0x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$ exists as a Lebesgue integral for $\alpha$ real and positive. My idea was to go by Lebesgue's Series Theorem. So I substituted the Maclaurin series for $e^{-x}$, but I realized that even if I were able to swap the summation with integration, I would still not be able to compute the integral from 0 to infinity. I am not sure what I should use, then, to prove that. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: I can provide a full proof if you wish, but it has nothing to do with the theorems/approaches you mention so I'm not sure how to hint it

Comment: @FShrike What does the proof use?

Comment: In case which $\alpha \geqslant 1$, your integrand is continuous and vanishes at infinity, so even the Riemann integral exists. In case of $\alpha < 1$, you similarly check what goes on around 0 and infinity.

Comment: It splits $\Gamma(\alpha)$ into $\Phi(\alpha)+\Psi(\alpha)$, where: $$\Phi(\alpha):=\int_0^1t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\\Psi(\alpha):=\int_1^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$And it can be shown that $\Psi$ is an *entire function*, i.e. convergent, continuous and infinitely differentiable on the entire complex plane, and it can be shown that $\Phi(\alpha)$ is convergent, continuous and infinitely differentiable in the right half-plane, i.e. for $\alpha\in\Bbb C:\Re[\alpha]\gt0$.

Comment: It is from a text on classic analysis, using only Riemann integration theory

Comment: I think a possible hint could be this: split the integral in the sum of three integrals and try to use the comparison test for integrals on two of those integrals.

Answer (score 1):

On any compact interval $[a,b] \subset (0, \infty),$ the integrand is continuous and therefore integrable. Thus, suffices to show the integrand is integrable on $[0, a)$ and $[b, \infty).$ By Taylor series, $e^{-x} = 1/e^x \leq k! x^{-k}$ for all $k,$ so $x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x} \leq k! x^{\alpha - 1 - k}$ on $x \geq k.$ The right hand side will be integrable as soon as $k > \alpha.$ On $[0, a),$ you will have $e^{-x} \leq 1$ and then $x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x} \leq x^{\alpha - 1}$ which is integrable on $[0, a)$ for $\alpha > 0.$